# How to get subtotals in excel sheet using POI in java

Tags: java

I want to get the subtotals in my excel sheet for grouped row using POI in java. Please can anyone provide an example how to use the function SUBTOTALS.

Task Name   Est Hours  Actual Hours

```
 TaskA        10          11
 TaskA        12          19
 TaskB        16          12
 TaskA        2           5
 TaskB        4           6 
 TaskC        10          7
 TaskC        9           11
 TaskB        20          14
 TaskC        3           9
```

Please can any one provide me a sample code for how to use SUBTOTALS function for the data in the excel sheet. I want to group same name tasks and get sum of Est Hrs and Actual Hrs for each task.

Comment: Can we have some sample data rows please, then we know what the shape of the data is.

Comment: Is FormulaEvaluator.evaluate(Cell cell) not what you need?